# Software for capturing how subsystems interact

Tags: open-source, requirements-management

I'm designing a system comprising several distinct subsystems, some of which are connected to each other in various ways e.g. analog signals, serial comms, etc.

I'd like to be able to capture the various subsystem interactions and also be able to create diagrams to easily visualise the interactions and connections between subsystems.

For software systems I'm aware of system sequence diagrams.  Are there similar tools for the broader world of engineering?

What type of software should I be looking for?

Comment: What's wrong with some boxes with labelled lines between them? I am not sure what you are looking for (but am very interested in the answer :-)